# Python Joining two dictionnary with similar content

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am looking for a Pythonic way (the less code possible) to unite the content of two dictionnaries :

```
basket1 = {"ham":2,"eggs":3}
basket2 = {"eggs":4,"spam":1}
```

I want to get a third basket that is going to be the "sum" of the two other, basket 3 should be:

```
basket3 --> {"ham":2,"eggs":7,"spam":1}
```

If possible, doing this using `set`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use a `Counter`, which is a kind of `defaultdict` with some nice properties:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> basket1 = {"ham":2,"eggs":3}
>>> basket2 = {"eggs":4,"spam":1}
>>> basket_sum = Counter(basket1) + Counter(basket2)
>>> basket_sum
Counter({'eggs': 7, 'ham': 2, 'spam': 1})
```

which you could convert back into a pure `dict` if you wanted:

```
>>> dict(basket_sum)
{'eggs': 7, 'ham': 2, 'spam': 1}
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it. Also, the usual link [to the reference](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Interesting use of counter

Comment: @Speccy: not directly.  But if you write a helper function to convert a list of `Food` instances to a dict, like `def basket_to_dict(basket): return {f.name: f.quantity for f in basket}`, then somethiing like `[Food(n,q) for n,q in (Counter(basket_to_dict(b1)) + Counter(basket_to_dict(b2))).iteritems()]` should work.  (Python >= 2.7.)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're trying to count the values, use `collections.Counter`:

```
basket3 = collections.Counter(basket1)
basket3.update(basket2)
```

Or:

```
basket3 = collections.Counter(basket1) + collections.Counter(basket2)
```

Comment: @Speccy: See the new version.

Comment: +1 for showing the `update` method. It is useful to know that `update` behaves differently for `Counter` type dicts.

Comment: Thanks, I will go for the most upvoted answer, which is basically the same as yours

Comment: @Speccy: It's probably better than mine for future searchers, because it shows more detail, so it was the right one to accept.

Comment: @abarnert, Would something like this work if I have for example a list of instances of the Food class (with properties name and quantity) and I wanted to remove the duplicate and update the total quantity for each unique instance of the Food class in the list?

Comment: @Speccy: You mean the count is a member of `Food`? No, in that case you need to do something different. You could always make two `Counter({food: quantity for food in foods})` objects, add them, then convert back to a list after the fact. But at that point, it might be simpler to just make two `set`s and do it manually, or add an `update` method to `Food`, or…

Answer (score 2):

```
In [2]: basket1 = {"ham":2,"eggs":3}

In [3]: basket2 = {"eggs":4,"spam":1}

In [4]: baskets = [basket1, basket2]

In [5]: answer = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [6]: for basket in baskets:
   ...:     for item in basket:
   ...:         answer[item] += basket[item]
   ...:         

In [7]: answer
Out[7]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'eggs': 7, 'ham': 2, 'spam': 1})

In [8]: dict(answer)
Out[8]: {'eggs': 7, 'ham': 2, 'spam': 1}
```

Comment: What is needed is the *sum* of the values for duplicate keys in the various dictionaries, not the number of dictionaries containing that particular key.

Comment: I think this could be repaired by changing `answer[item] += 1` to `answer[item] += basket[item]`.

Comment: That's what I meant to do. Fixed!

Comment: Wait, how can you get `eggs` of 9?

Comment: @DSM: That was a leaked `answer` from the previous trial. See updated